# Google Drive SDK: convert MSWORD to PDF - ExportLinks NULL

Tags: google-drive-api

When I have a File in Google Drive that is a native Google Docs document, then I have access to `exportLinks` for different mime-types, also for PDF;

But I have MSWORD documents that have been generated. The `exportLinks` property is always `null` for MSWORD document. In the web interface I can print which downloads a perfectly converted PDF document.

**Question: can I generate a PDF from a MSWORD file somehow using the SDK  ?**

Been up and down through the docs looking for clues.

The download/print link downloads from a real long URI :

```
https://doc-0o-a0-docsviewer.googleusercontent.com/viewer/securedownload/1ve0rd17der7n5d32lker62ffdq2175h/<randomstring>/<longnumber>/<randomstring>=/<randomstring>/<randomstring>==?docid=<randomstring>&chan=<randomstring>&dom=<googleappsdomain>&sec=<randomstring>&a=gp&filename=<filename>&nonce=<nonce>&user=<userid>&hash=<hasvalue>
```

anybody ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExportLinks are only provided for documents in Google-native formats, so you'll have to convert the MS Word document to Google Docs before you can export it as pdf (and other supported file formats).

Comment: I was afraid so ... :-( The web interface provides the functionality though.

Comment: related question to do so : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663419/insert-operation-with-convert-flag-true-fails

Comment: @Claudio I want to do streaming of google drive file. I am able to get downloadUrl and in browser i m able to play but it is first downloading and than playing. How can I get export url... Please if u have any idea let me know...