# Insert operation with convert flag TRUE fails

Tags: google-drive-api

I am generating reports resulting in WORD files using xdocreport.

From the generated report, I create a `InputStreamContent` with MIME-TYPE `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"` (MS WORD - DOCX) to write to Google Drive :

```
// create Word file stream using xdocreport
OutputStream2InputStream outputStream = new OutputStream2InputStream(); // buffer
report.process(context, outputStream);
// create inputstream for Google Drive
InputStreamContent inputStream = new InputStreamContent("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        outputStream.getInputStream());
inputStream.setLength(outputStream.size());
```

**WRITING MSWORD DOCUMENT WORKS FINE (CONVERT= FALSE) :**

```
File file = new File();
Insert insertOperation = service.files().insert(file, inputStream).setConvert(false);
file.setTitle("test.docx");
file.setMimeType(inputstream.getType());
File result = insertOperation.execute();
```

Resulting in a WORD DOCX file created on my Google Drive.

**WRITING SAME INPUTSTREAM WITH CONVERT=TRUE FAILS**

```
File file = new File();
Insert insertOperation = service.files().insert(file, inputStream).setConvert(true);
file.setTitle("test");
//file.setMimeType(inputstream.getType()); // what here ? 
File result = insertOperation.execute();
```

**RESULT**

*1. When NOT setting the mime type :* newly created File `result` has **0 bytes** and **MIME-type: application/vnd.google-apps.kix**

*2. When setting the mime type :* MIME-TYPE set to "application/vnd.google-apps.document" and convert = true, results in 400: BAD REQUEST.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem. Don't set a MIME type in the request metadata. Google Drive will decide the MIME type to convert to.

Your line marked `// what here ?` should be left out.

Comment: When I leave out setting the MIME type on the Insert instance, the resulting file has 0 bytes and MIME-type: application/vnd.google-apps.kix. Or do I have to leave it out on the InputStreamContent ?

Comment: On the InputStreamContent you should use the actual MIME type of the file. You should never have to pass the "kix" MIME type.

Comment: AFAICS, I do everything as you explain... but results in file with 0 bytes - the same InputStreamContent works fine without convert. I need to dig a bit deeper, i'm afraid.

Comment: turned out to be a stupid bug setting the mime type earlier on in the code. thx for the help;

Comment: @AliAfshar is it possible to get public url of google drive files. i tried but i m able to get downloadurl

Answer (score 0):

All what you need to do is to update your getType() with the correct .docx MIME-type.

```
docx=>   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

I had the same issue and this piece of code fixed it!